# Is the module @react-native-community/blur is working

Tags: react-native, module, blur

I am building an android app by using react native and I would like to BlurView for a modal message.
so, I have installed @react-native-community/blur module and run project.
but it shows a message as following:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.eightbitlab:blurview:1.6.3.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :react-native-community_blur
      > Could not resolve com.eightbitlab:blurview:1.6.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/eightbitlab/blurview/1.6.3/blurview-1.6.3.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/eightbitlab/blurview/1.6.3/blurview-1.6.3.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2,
TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Could not resolve com.eightbitlab:blurview:1.6.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/eightbitlab/blurview/1.6.3/blurview-1.6.3.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/eightbitlab/blurview/1.6.3/blurview-1.6.3.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2,
TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
      > Could not resolve com.eightbitlab:blurview:1.6.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://www.jitpack.io/com/eightbitlab/blurview/1.6.3/blurview-1.6.3.pom'.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://www.jitpack.io/com/eightbitlab/blurview/1.6.3/blurview-1.6.3.pom'.
               > The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2,
TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
                  > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you end up solving the problem?